# Cannot run pg_basebackup in powershell

Tags: postgresql, powershell

We are trying to run a `pg_basebackup` script on Windows in Powershell.  The command seems to work in the windows command line (`cmd`), but not in `powershell` on some machines.  We are running Powershell as admin.  Has anyone run into this?

The following is the command we are running:

```
pg_basebackup --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username="test" --password="testpassword" --progress --verbose -D "C:\test\master\base_backups\test"
```

Comment: Describe "doesn't work", please. Also, `--password` doesn't accept an argument.

Comment: Thanks re: --password.  By "Doesn't work", I mean that powershell looks like it's trying to do something, but does nothing and doesn't spit out any output.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
# Put here your pg_basebackup file location
Set-Location "C:\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin" 
# Put Here your password
$env:PGPASSWORD = "testpassword" 
[string]$job = .\pg_basebackup --% -U test --progress --verbose -D "C:\test\master\base_backups\test"
```

The result will be in `$job` variable.